# SQL Query creating help needed

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables in my databse, I need query, which result will be Tweet, nickname of user, who wrote this tweet and pubdate.But I need tweets only from those people which I'm follow. In 111212_follow table we can see follower_id, this is who is following, I need result only about people  which follower_id following(followed_id). Follower_id and followed_id are ID's of users from  111212_users table. Thank you all for help.

I have 1 example of working query i don't know how use it in my case.

```
"SELECT tweet_id, poster_id, t112586_users.username as poster, tweet_message, post_date, t112586_users.pics FROM t112586_tweets 
            INNER JOIN t112586_users ON t112586_tweets.poster_id = t112586_users.user_id 
            WHERE poster_id IN(SELECT followee FROM t112586_followers where follower = $id)
            ORDER BY post_date DESC;"
```

UPDATE: 
I have working query, but this one doesn't give me nickname and pubdate. `$userId` I'm taking from session, this variable give us know id of user's as we logged in

```
"SELECT 111212_tweets.user_id, 111212_tweets.text FROM 111212_tweets INNER JOIN 111212_follow ON 111212_tweets.user_id=111212_follow.followed WHERE 111212_follow.follower='$userId'"


    ---------------------------------------
    111212_follow
    ---------------------------------------     
    follow_id | followed_id | follower_id |
    ---------------------------------------
       3      |     2       |      7      |
    ---------------------------------------
       5      |     1       |      7      |
    ---------------------------------------

    ---------------------------------------------
    111212_tweets
    ---------------------------------------------      
       id        | user_id  |    tweet | pubdate |
    ---------------------------------------------
       3         |    2     |    text  | date    |
    ---------------------------------------------
       4         |    1     |    text  | date    |
    ---------------------------------------------
       5         |    1     |    text  | date    |
    ---------------------------------------------

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    111212_users
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
       id        |    name         |    nickname    |    email  |  password
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1         |    Sten         |      user1     | t1@t.com  |  123123
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
       2         |    Mark         |      user2     | t2@t.com  | 123123
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
       7         |    John         |      user3     | t3@t.com  | 123123
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

UPDATE:

```
<ul id="tweetDisplay">
            <p>Tweets: </p>
            <?php
            $userId = $_SESSION['userId'];
            $query = "SELECT T1.`tweet`, T2.`nickname`,T1.`pubdate`FROM `111212_tweets` T1 LEFT JOIN `111212_users` T2 ON T1.`user_id` = T2.`id` LEFT JOIN `111212_follow` T3 ON T1.`user_id` = T3.`followed_id` WHERE T3.`follower_id` = '$userId'";
            $searchQuery = mysql_query($query);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($searchQuery)){
            echo "----------------------------------------------";
            echo "<li>Nickname: ".$row['nickname']."</li><li>".$row['text']."</li><li class='date'>".$row['pubdate']."</li>";
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Strawberry just a table prefix I'm assuming

Comment: Yes, 111212 is prefix

Comment: @vladja First fix your PHP code and try the simplest query like SELECT 'test'; when it's working, only then you're ready to start working on your query.

Comment: It's interesting that I got a TRUE when used `"SELECT 111212_tweets.user_id, 111212_tweets.text FROM 111212_tweets INNER JOIN 111212_follow ON 111212_tweets.user_id=111212_follow.followed WHERE 111212_follow.follower='$userId'"` without any changes in PhP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query, replace YOUR_ID with the id of the user you're logged in with:

```
SELECT
    T1.`tweet`,
    T2.`nickname`,
    T1.`pubdate`
FROM `111212_tweets` T1
LEFT JOIN `111212_users` T2
ON T1.`user_id` = T2.`id`
LEFT JOIN `111212_follow` T3
ON T1.`user_id` = T3.`followed_id`
WHERE T3.`follower_id` = 'YOUR_ID'
```

Comment: After doing this squry I'm trying to write all using `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($searchQuery)){
            echo "----------------------------------------------";
            echo "<li>Nickname: ".$row['nickname']."</li><li>".$row['text']."</li><li class='date'>".$row['pubdate']."</li>";
            }` But i have error `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\main.php on line 54` Is it means that query returns false?

Comment: @vladja check your $searchQuery variable, it has to be a SQL result object, not a query string. Look at the example #2 here how it's done: http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Comment: Yes, it is. `$searchQuery = mysql_query($query);`

Comment: @vladja I can't tell you what's wrong with it, you need to post more information/source code. According to the warning, something is wrong with $searchQuery variable. No this warning does not mean query returned empty result set. You can check your query result with another tools, like: phpMyAdmin

Comment: Updated 1st post with full code. `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($searchQuery)){`   line which error talking about

Comment: @vladja as I have told you look at example #2 on this page: http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array, it seems like your $searchQuery is FALSE, because you have to connect to the database first.

Comment: sorry, forgot to write that i connected to database at the beggining of file.  `<?php include "lib/connect.php";?>`  file code `<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('tweeter');?>`

Comment: @vladja do var_dump($searchQuery); after $searchQuery = mysql_query($query); If it's false then something is wrong with your PHP code, not query.

Comment: mmm, YES, It is false... But i don't know what could heppen whith so little number of php lines. But Thank you very much for your HELP.